# What is causing the Inconsistent property declaration error?

Tags: vb6

I am getting the inconsistent property compiler error in the Let Property code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Property Let CellEntered(ByVal uNewValue As Boolean, ByVal uCaller As String)

    If uNewValue Then
        If InIDE() Then
            SetFormCaption frmMain, "enter caller: " & uCaller
        End If
    End If

    m_bCellEntered = uNewValue

End Property
Public Property Get CellEntered() As Boolean

    CellEntered = m_bCellEntered

End Property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of parameters must be consistent between the Let and the Get.

`Let CellEntered` cannot have an extra `uCaller` parameter.

You can use a method to handle the `uCaller` parameter:

```
Public Property Let CellEntered(ByVal uNewValue As Boolean)
    m_bCellEntered = uNewValue
End Property
Public Property Get CellEntered() As Boolean
    CellEntered = m_bCellEntered
End Property

Public Sub EnterCell(ByVal uCaller As String)
    If InIDE() Then
        SetFormCaption frmMain, "enter caller: " & uCaller
    End If
    CellEntered = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I never noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, the parameters must be consistent.  You can do the following to make them consistent:

```
Public Property Let CellEntered(ByVal uCaller As String, ByVal uNewValue As Boolean)
   If uNewValue Then
      If InIDE() Then
         SetFormCaption frmMain, "enter caller: " & uCaller
      End If
   End If
    
   m_bCellEntered = uNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get CellEntered(ByVal uCaller As String) As Boolean
   CellEntered = m_bCellEntered
End Property
```

It should be noted that any additional parameters must come BEFORE the value.